# Operator norm equality

Tags: operator-theory, lp-spaces

I came across this problem and am getting stuck on how to prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Suppose $L:C(\textbf{T}) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where $L(f)=\int_0^1 {f(x)g(x)}dx$ for all $f \in C(\textbf{T})$ (the v.s. of continuous, 1-periodic functions on $\mathbb{R}$). Then $\|L\|=\|g\|_1$, where $\|L\|$ is the operator norm of $L$ and $\|g\|_1=\int_0^1|g(x)|dx$.

My approach is to show $\|L\|\leq\|g\|_1$ and $\|L\|\geq\|g\|_1$. I know that L is a linear functional on $C(\textbf{T})$ and 
I know that $\|L(f)\|=\|\int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx\| \leq \int_0^1 \|f(x)g(x)\|dx$ but am not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Is $L$ bounded? Or are there conditions on $g$? Note that $f(x)g(x)$ is a scalar.

Comment: Expanding on copper.hat's note: It's $|L(f)|$, not $\|L(f)\|$; $|\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)\,dx|$, not $\|\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)\,dx\|$; and $\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)g(x)|\,dx$, not $\int_{0}^{1}\|f(x)g(x)\|\,dx$.

Comment: Oh ok. So I think I proved that $\|L\| \leq \|g\|_1$: $|Lf|=|\int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx|\leq\int_0^1|f(x)g(x)|dx \leq \|g\|_1$ since $|f|\leq 1$ by definition of operator norm. I'm still stuck on the other direction though. I'm looking at functions $g_n=\frac{\overline{g}}{|g|+1/n}$, $n=1,2,3,...$. As $n$ increases, $g_n \rightarrow \frac{\overline{g}}{|g|}$, but I am not sure where to go from there.

Comment: @user178390 : The problem with the reverse inequality is that you cannot choose $f$ to be an arbitrary measurable function; it has to be continuous because you want the norm of $L : C(T)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. So, for example, you can't set $f=\overline{g}/|g|$ for $g \ne 0$ and $0$ otherwise--this is because $g$ is not necessarily continuous. However, if you can find $\{ f_{n} \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with $\|f_{n}\|_{C(T)}\le 1$ such that $\{ f_{n}\}$ converges pointwise a.e. to $\overline{g}/|g|$, then the effect is the same. Do you know that $C$ is dense in $L^{1}$? Do you know Hahn-Banach?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. $|f(x)| \le \|f\|$.
2. Approximate $|g|$ by a linear combination of indicator functions for disjoint closed sets.